# Moving range slider using Selenium(python)

Tags: jquery, python, selenium

trying to move a range slider.
Here is html from DBM bid manager.
In the case below we are talking about a 2 sliders bar that indicates ages range.

```
<div class="BK62FH-Ge-a" id="gwt-debug-demographicEditor-ageRangeEditor">
<div tabindex="0" class="BK62FH-Ub-a BK62FH-Ub-c BK62FH-Ub-d BK62FH-Ge-c" id="gwt-debug-demographicEditor-ageRangeEditor-ageRangeSlider" style="width: 204px; padding-right: 5px;">
    <input type="text" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">
    <div>
        <ol class="BK62FH-Ub-j">
            ...
        </ol>
        <div tabindex="0">
            <input type="text" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">
            <div>
                <div tabindex="0" class="BK62FH-Ub-f BK62FH-Ub-i" style="left: 0px;">
                    <input type="text" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">
                    <span class="BK62FH-Ub-g">V</span>
                </div>
                <div tabindex="0" class="BK62FH-Ub-f BK62FH-Ub-h" style="left: 204px;">
                    <input type="text" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">
                    <span class="BK62FH-Ub-g">V</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div tabindex="0" class="BK62FH-Ub-e" style="left: 0px; width: 204px;">
            <input type="text" tabindex="-1" role="presentation" style="opacity: 0; height: 1px; width: 1px; z-index: -1; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;">
        </div>
    </div>
</div> 
<span class="gwt-CheckBox BK62FH-Ge-d" id="gwt-debug-demographicEditor-ageRangeEditor-includeUnknownCheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="on" id="gwt-debug-demographicEditor-ageRangeEditor-includeUnknownCheckbox-input" tabindex="0" checked="">
    <label for="gwt-debug-demographicEditor-ageRangeEditor-includeUnknownCheckbox-input" id="gwt-debug-demographicEditor-ageRangeEditor-includeUnknownCheckbox-label">
        <ui:message description="Text for include unknown age range checkbox in demographic targeting."> Include unknown </ui:message>
    </label>
</span> 
<div class="gwt-Label BK62FH-Ge-b" id="gwt-debug-demographicEditor-ageRangeEditor-ageTextLabel">All ages</div>
```

Was trying to use ActionChains methods and it didn't work...

Comment: How exactly you tried to use `ActionChains`? Show some code.. Does this slider visible on page or you should slide down page to see slider? What browser you use?

Comment: I'm using chrome driver [code]from selenium.webdriver.common import ActionChains
actions  = ActionChains(driver)
elem.driver.find_element_by_class_name('BK62FH-Ub-i')
actions.drag_and_drop_by_offset(elem, 34, 0).perform()

Comment: both sliders are going crazy when performing that...

Comment: I'm not sure that this will resolve your issue, but I advise you to use `Firefox` instead of `Chrome` as `Chrome` cannot correctly behave with modules such as `common.Keys`, `common.ActionChains`...